# How logout user when one of APIs responds Unauthorized 401 (Nuxt-Auth)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

How logout user when one of APIs responds Unauthorized 401 with Nuxt-Auth?
I use AXIOS & built-in functions of Nuxt-Auth for requests

My nuxt-config settings for nuxt-auth:

```js
    auth: {
        redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            logout: '/',
            callback: '/login',
            home: '/panel/dashboard'
        },
        strategies: {
            local: {
                token: {
                    property: 'token',
                    global: true,
                    type: 'Bearer',
                    required: true,
                },
                user: {
                    property: 'user',
                    autoFetch: true
                },
                endpoints: {
                    login: {url: '/api/auth/login_verify', method: 'post'},
                    logout: {url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'get'},
                    user: {url: '/api/auth/validate', method: 'get'},
                },
            },
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Axios, it'll be easy to use [Interceptors](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers/#interceptors) and catch the error according to your requirement and then call the logout action

Something like below with a plugin created in `src/plugins/axios.js` will work

```
export default function ({ $axios }) {
  $axios.onError((error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      CALL_LOGOUT_ACTION_HERE
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: That will destroy default nuxt header on error, and app will be lagged in some request

Comment: $auth is not present here how are you calling the logout action?

Answer (score 1):

pass context instead of `$axios`:

```js
export default function (context) {
    context.$axios.onError((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            context.$auth.logout()
        }
    })
}
```